# Condition for the equality of truth assignments of a given formula

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

So, here's the theorem that I'm trying to prove;

Let $\delta$ be any formula in $L_p$ and let $u$ and $v$ be truth assignments such that $u(A_n) = v(A_n)$ for every atomic formula $A_n$ that occurs in $\delta$. Then, $u(\delta) = v(\delta)$.

---

Proof Attempt:

We proceed by induction on the number of connectives of $\delta$.

If $\delta$ has $0$ connectives, then it is an atomic formula. Hence, $u(\delta) = v(\delta)$.

Now, suppose that that the assertion holds for any formula with $k \leq n$ connectives. Let $\delta'$ be a formula with $n+1$ connectives and suppose that $u(A_k) = v(A_k)$ for every atomic formula $A_k$ in $\delta'$. Due to the unique readability theorem, there is a formula $\alpha$ such that:

$$\delta' "=" (\lnot \alpha)$$

or there exist formulas $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that:

$$\delta' "=" (\beta \to \gamma)$$

In the first case, all of the atomic formulas of $\delta'$ are the same as the atomic formulas of $\alpha$, except that $\alpha$ has $n$ connectives. Hence, $u(\alpha) = v(\alpha)$. By the definition of the truth assignment, $u(\delta') = v(\delta')$.

In the second case, we know that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ both have a total of $n$ connectives. Moreover, because they share atomic formulas with $\delta'$, $u(\beta) = v(\beta)$ and $u(\gamma) = v(\gamma)$. By the definition of the truth assignment, $u(\delta') = v(\delta')$.

In all cases, $u(\delta') = v(\delta')$. Hence, it follows that the assertion holds for formulas with $n+1$ connectives. This proves that the assertion holds for any formula $\delta$ in $L_p$. $\Box$

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you have to add some details to the part "By the definition of the truth assignment..." for the case $\to$ :-)

Comment: Ah, I meant this. 

If $u(\beta) = v(\beta)$ and $u(\gamma) = v(\gamma)$, then whatever values these truth assignments take, there is a definite prescription for assigning truth values to $(\beta \to \gamma)$ and assigning a truth value to that formula by means of $u$ and $v$ won't make a difference (since the truth value of $(\beta \to \gamma)$ is entirely dependent on the truth values of $\beta$ and $\gamma$). Hence, $u(\delta') = v(\delta')$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Alright nice, thank you Professor Scott and, uh, I guess Professor Allegranza? I'm not quite sure what to refer to you as haha but thank you so much :)